# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' while running yarn run storybook with vue-loader

Tags: vue.js, storybook, vue-loader

`yarn run storybook` failed with error

specific details are :

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js

You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

Storybook **5.2.3**

webpack **4.41.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

This lead me to another error

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined. found in

and it got resolved when I added

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                    transpileOnly: true
                },
            }
        ],
    });

    return config;
};
```

and removed the previous `vue-loader` section.

---

After trying out different options, error got resolved when a `webpack.config.js` file was created in `.storybook/` folder with the following content.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: require.resolve('vue-loader'),
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
    });
    return config;
};
```

Important thing is resolving loader plugin like this **require.resolve('vue-loader')** and then **re-run** the yarn command again.